# Multiple functions within a Module

Tags: scoping

I have a function that extracts a  numerical value from two vectors, written as `Spa[i_,j_]:=Flatten[LaU[i].LaD[j]][[1]]`. (Note, I'm sure that this isn't the most efficient way to solve this problem but it works for my uses). In the next stage of my process, I'm having to calculate Spa functions when the argument needs something other than `LaU`, like something called `QLaU[1]`, which is defined in a similar process (exact same dimensions etc).

Instead of manually creating a separate function like e.g `SpaQ[i_,j_] :=Flatten[QLaU[1].LaD[2]][[1]]`, I'm hoping to use a `Module` function to simply combine the two together, and have MMA recognise the type of function. Is this possible within the scope of `Module`? I'm essentially trying to put a couple of functions within the single overall `Spa` function, to keep the final results looking similar.

Comment: `Spa[lau_,i_,j_]:=Flatten[lau[i].LaD[j]][[1]]`?

Comment: May I ask how that works? Spa with three arguments means I need to specify three bits of information, and I'm not sure how that would work for both LaU and QLaU?

Comment: Pass the symbol name `LaU` or `QLaU` as an argument to `Spa`. That is what Alan is implying in his comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to constrain `Spa` to only accept `LaU` and `LaD`, whichis good practice, you can define it like this:

```
Spa[la:(LaU | LaD), i_, j_] := Flatten[la[i].LaU[j]][[1]]
```